# Why ubuntu 11.10 hangs frequenty?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I am using Ubuntu from a long time and recently I have shifted to its newest version 11.10, Its interface is nice but my touch-pad got hanged frequently after short intervals of time, then no key or key combination works, The only option is that I have to restart of logout from my laptop.

I have tried a lot to solve this problem but not found any satisfactory help till now. 
Most of my friends who are using Ubuntu 11.10 reported me the same, seems like its a bug or something else.

Please let me know that how to get out of this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: http://superuser.com/ is a better site for this question.

Comment: Thank You. I am new to stackoverflow and was unaware of its FAQ so posted my question here.